# How can I make a generic sort method to sort a HashMap of ArrayLists of multiple types?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, hashmap

I'm trying to selection sort a passed HashMap of ArrayLists but I'm kind of stuck. I'm not sure how to make it a generic method that works on ints, doubles, and strings. I've looked at past questions similar to this but I still don't understand.Any help or guidance is appreciated.

```
public static HashMap sort_list(HashMap lists) {

    HashMap sorted_lists = new HashMap();

    ArrayList<Integer> sorted_ints = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Double> sorted_doubles = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> sorted_strings = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList list_of_ints = (ArrayList) lists.get("ints");
    ArrayList list_of_doubles = (ArrayList) lists.get("doubles");
    ArrayList list_of_strings = (ArrayList) lists.get("strings");

    //My sort code below (which doesn't work with this implementation)
    int min;

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.size() - 1; i++) {

        min = i;

        for(int j = i + 1; j < arr.size(); j++) {

            if(arr.get(j) < arr.get(min)) {
                min = j;
            }
        }

        int temp = arr.get(min);
        arr.set(min, arr.get(i));
        arr.set(i, temp);
    }
    // return hashmap
    return sorted_lists;
}
```

Comment: Do not use *raw* generic types. Always add `<...>` after `HashMap` and `ArrayList`.

Comment: It is very unclear what it is you're trying to sort. What is `arr`? --- Also, you can't have a `List` of `int` values, because primitive types cannot be used with generics. Did you mean for `list_of_ints` to be an `ArrayList<Integer>` perhaps? --- And why don't you just call the `sort()` method?

Comment: @Andreas: True, but **if** there was a sensible `<..., ValueType>`, then the question could nearly be answered already. The point is: Using heterogeneous list types like this smells like a design error. It would be **really** hard to justify this kind of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java already provides a facility to sort `Lists`, provided the elements in the `List` implement the `Comparable` interface. It's called `Collections.sort` [check it out](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)). That is the correct way to do a "generic sort": implement the appropriate interface exactly like `Collections.sort` requires.